# ByRef not working in VBA with value type from a class

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

I always used `ByRef` successfully, until now. I need a function to modify a `Double` from a class-object. To illustrate, consider the following program.

```
Class1.cls:
Public d As Double
```

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Class1, d As Double
    Set c = New Class1

    c.d = 5
    d = 5

    ChangeVar c.d
    ChangeVar d

    Debug.Print c.d
    Debug.Print d
End Sub

Sub ChangeVar(ByRef d As Double)
    d = 10
End Sub
```

For my surprise, the above example will output

```
5
10
```

Anybody?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood `aClassInstance.publicVariable` is encapsulated as a hidden property get/let pair, so passing `ByRef` is passing the address of the hidden `get` properties return value, not the underlying variable declared in the class.

You can test this by examining the addresses of the 2 forms of `d` within the class; they will be different

```
(class_init)
debug.? " d address=" & VarPtr(d)
debug.? ".d address=" & VarPtr(me.d)
```

Comment: Hum, thanks! Now, how can I possibly fix that? Unfortunately, I still need that function to modify the value.

Comment: You could `temp = c.d : ChangeVar temp : c.d = temp` or expose a `.changeD(incrementor)` method or `Sub ChangeVar(cls As Class1) : cls.d = cls.d+1`

Comment: So, I suppose it's not possible using only ByRef and my PublicVariable?

Comment: No I don't believe so, the "raw" `d` is not exposed outside of the class, why do you have to do it that way? there are several alternatives

Comment: Well, I don't *have* to, but it would be the cleanest way, don't you agree? Actually, isn't this what one would expect of ByRef? Sorry if I seem a bit rough right now, but I'm a little pissed off on VBA because of this. Your answer was great, and I'll probably accept it if nothing comes by that fixes it as I'd like.

Comment: One purpose of having a property in a class is so that the class has control over it.  If you change your Property Let procedure to include some validation and someone was able to change that property outside of the class, your validation wouldn't run.  I get that you're not using Property Let, but Public variables in a class are just a shortcut, they still follow the same rules.

Comment: Thanks, Dick. That makes sense, but doesn't justify such behavior. Maybe it's subjective, but when I see a property passed ByRef I'd expect the function to be ably to modify it - even if it is through its Property Let. However, I understand that what is being passed is in fact the return value of Property Get.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue myself, its cleaner workaround is turning it into a function

```
Sub Test()     
    Dim c As Class1, d As Double     
    Set c = New Class1      
    c.d = 5     
    d = 5      
    c.d = ChangeVar(c.d)     
    d = ChangeVar(d)     
    Debug.Print c.d     
    Debug.Print d 
End Sub  

Public function ChangeVar(d As Double)     
    ChangeVar = 10 
End Function
```