# Passing VBA Variable by reference to class function

Tags: vba

I have a custom class with various Get/Let properties

```
Property Get pGasIP() As Double
    pGasIP = zpGasIP
End Property

Property Let pGasIP(ByVal NewValue As Double)
    zpGasIP = NewValue
End Property
```

Along with functions that reference these variables:

```
Public Sub CalcProduction(Index As Long, life As Double)

zoGasProdStartGross = TypeCurve("cum", -Base + 1, pGasTimeRestricted, _
pGasIP, pGasDi, pGasDiHyp, pGasBFactor, 0.06, pGasQab, pCurtailment)

End Sub
```

I am trying to iterate on the variables within this function by passing a reference to the desired variable in a Breakeven function as follows (iterative variable refers to the class property that I would like to reference, ObjFunction refers to an output value that I would like to reference and change)

```
Public Sub Breakeven(ByRef iterativeVariable As Variant, ByRef ObjFunction as variant)
Dim DesiredValue as Double, CurrentDistance as Double

'set up incremental calculation
    IterativeVariable = IterativeVariable + .001
    CurrentDistance = DesiredValue - ObjFunction

'calculate new value with incremented variable 
    CalcProduction 600, 600
    CurrentDistane = DesiredValue - ObjFunction
```

When I try to pass the object properties in a normal module, the values of the corresponding class properties are being passed rather than the reference.  Is there a way to pass object properties into a subroutine that can modify/calculate them?

Thanks!

Jordan

**EDIT:**

I am trying to pass the following argument in a normal module:

```
Object.Breakeven Object.GasIP, Object.GasEUR
```

I want the actual references to the properties passed in (so I can modify them), but this nomenclature passes in the value of the properties instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ByRef not working in VBA with value type from a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587324/byref-not-working-in-vba-with-value-type-from-a-class)

Comment: Andre, I think what I am trying to accomplish is different from the example you linked to because I don't have an explicit variable I am trying to pass.  I would like the function to be flexible enough to take any user specified object property and change.

Comment: I know. In any case, the true reference won't be passed, but a ghost one that is used temporarily by the property. Are you sure that isn't your problem too? Please let me know.

Comment: Andre, you nailed it.  Any suggestions on how to pass a true reference or a good workaround for someone relatively new to object oriented programming?

Comment: Some answers to my question provide suggestions on how to go about it.  The simplest is to expose the internal variables of the properties, and use them directly. VBA's OOP is very weak (one could say "it just plain sucks"), so don't feel too compelled by usual best practices like hiding variables behind properties at every single turn.

Answer (score 1):

It's hackish and probably glacially slow, but you can manipulate object properties on the fly using `CallByName`. Here's an example:

```
Sub modismod(o1 As Object, prop1$, o2 As Object, prop2$)
    Dim i1&, i2&
    i1 = CallByName(o1, prop1, VbGet)
    i2 = CallByName(o2, prop2, VbGet)
    i1 = i1 + 1
    i2 = i2 - 1
    CallByName o1, prop1, VbLet, i1
    CallByName o2, prop2, VbLet, i2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks rdhs this did the trick.  For my needs the speed shouldn't be too much of any issue.